# How to use python scipy.optimize.OptimizeResult and scipy.optimize.least_squares returns?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy

I am fitting a plane equation to a set of eight or so 3D points (x,y,z):

a*x + b*y + c*z + d = 0 using `scipy.optimize.minimize()` and comparing it to `scipy.optimize.least_squares()`

sol.x nicely gives me the solutions for the optimized plane parameters (a,b,c,d) and the parameters I get from each result (`least_squares` vs. `minimize`) match fairly well (within 0.001 percent of each other).

Here is my least squares fit:

```
def leastsq_fit(xyzArray):
     def f_min(xyz,params):
          plane_xyz = params[0:3]
          distance = (plane_xyz*xyz.T).sum(axis=1) + params[3]
          return distance / np.linalg.norm(plane_xyz)
     def residuals(params, xyz):
         return f_min(xyz, params)
     p0 = [0.1,0.2,1,0.4]
     sol = least_squares(residuals, p0, args=(xyzArray))
     return sol.x
```

and my minimize orthogonal distance (ODR) fit:

```
def fit_to_plane(xlist,ylist,zlist):
""" makes a plane fitted to points """

    def model(params, xyz):
         a,b,c,d = params
         x,y,z = xyz
         norm = math.sqrt(a**2 + b**2 + c**2)   
         eqn = a*x + b*y + c*z + d 
         sumsq = ((np.abs(eqn))**2).sum() / norm
         return sumsqb

   def unit_length(params):
        a,b,c,d = params
        return a**2 + b**2 + c**2 - 1 
  cons = ({'type':'eq', 'fun':unit_length}) # constrained by unit length
  initial_guess = 0.1,0.2,1,0.4
  sol = optimize.minimize(model, initial_guess, args=([xlist,ylist,zlist]),constraints=cons)
  return sol.x
```

I know I can get the sum of squared orthogonal distances for the ODR fit by doing:

`model(sol.x,[np.array(xlist),np.array(ylist),np.array(zlist)])`

but I am less sure how to get the same thing for the `least_squares` fit.

I believe that this result gives the overall "goodness-of-fit" but I also want to know the individual goodness-of-fit for the individual parameters of the plane (a,b,c,d). These will be useful for establishing rough "error bars" on planes fit to different similar sets of data.

Is it possible to use the other output products of these fits (sol.jac, sol.grad, etc.) to establish these parameter goodnesses of fit?

Comment: You can use J^T * J as an approximation to the hessian

Comment: THe diagonals in the hessian are ~ the estimates on the errors on the parameters, and the off diagonals are the correlations